# What is the easiest way to draw lattice points using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

What is the easiest way to draw lattice points using TikZ? What about changing the vector basis?

Comment: It's usually better to not use specific lingo. Do you mean drawing a bunch of black dots at regular intervals, possibly with different spacing horizontally and vertically?

Comment: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/lattice-points/

Comment: @TorbjørnT. yes, you nailed it.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner yes, I have seen it, but that seems complicated example.

Comment: I think this question was prematurely closed. The thread that is supposedly a duplicate is more complicated than you probably need, and more complicated than you probably can handle. If you still don't know how to proceed I suggest to edit your question in order to add a drawing that shows what you need. Then you will either get better pointers or the question is reopened for answers.

Comment: It all depends on what OP needs in his diagram. Does he needs fundamental domain? Does he need the standard x/y-axes? Does he need to refer to the lattice points for later markup? etc. The "easiest" way depends on the demand.